# Creating a Stopwatch in a Data Entry Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm fairly new to using VBA in Access.  What I'm trying to do is record how long it takes for someone to complete a data entry form from start to finish.  I have a text box with a timer in it that starts the moment the form is open but it won't stop/reset until it is closed.

The timer should start the moment they make a selection from a combobox I have in the form and finish the moment they click the Save button.  The Timer should then Reset/Start when they start the data entry process again.  The Save button I have already has some code in it that Updates one table and inserts data into two other tables.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the code I have for the timer in the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Static TimeCountStart
    If TimeCountStart = Empty Then
        TimeCountStart = Now
    End If
    Me!Count = Now() - TimeCountStart
    Me.TimerInterval = 1000
End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What's your question or issue that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Create a `ComboBox_Change` method in your userform to detect when the user makes a selection, then call your timer start method from there. Create `UserForm_Deactivate` and/or `UserForm_Terminate` method(s) and turn off the timer from there.

Comment: Thanks PeterT that worked perfect!!